# How to call a method from another method with arguments

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I want to call another method from the **updateButtonPressed** method.
This is what I tried:

```
-(IBAction) updateButtonPressed{
    [self loadScrollViewWithPage];
}
```

But the problem is that the **loadScrollViewWithPage** method has arguments. That method is like this:

```
- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {
 }
```

How can I call this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (IBAction) updateButtonPressed{
   int tempValue=5;
   [self loadScrollViewWithPage:tempValue];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you are wondering how to pass arguments along with messages to objects, is that right? Try:

```
-(IBAction) updateButtonPressed{
    int foo = 4;
    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:foo]; // a colon, followed by the argument
}
```

I suggest you read up on the Objective-C language in general, though.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/introduction/introobjectivec.html